# Is anything wrong with how I change views?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I only ever need 1 view at any given time. I'm targeting ios 6 and using arc.

I have a MasterViewController which all my views inherit from, so they all have this method:

```
-(void) showNextView:(UIViewController*)newController
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:true];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:newController animated:false];
    [self viewDidChange];
}
```

So in a subclass of MasterViewController we might have:

```
-(IBAction)gameButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if(sender == self.btnEmotion)
    {
        [self showNextView:[[EmotionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]];
    }
}
```

The root view controller is a navigation bar. But basically I make it so there is only ever 1 view.

However, when I test dealloc of the master view controller, it is never called. I'm not sure if this means a leak or if it's something I do not understand.

Is there anything wrong with how I am changing views?

Thanks

Comment: Upvoted for (1) clear presentation and (2) noticing and thinking clearly about the `dealloc` problem, and asking about it. Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:true];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:newController animated:false];
```

This does not do what you think. `newController` is the top view controller after the push, so the pop does nothing. Thus you are just piling up view controllers on top of view controllers. This is why nothing is ever dealloced.

You *might* try this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:newController animated:NO];
```

But I haven't tried it, and I'm unclear on what you're trying to accomplish, so I guarantee nothing...

However, all things considered, I feel this is a misuse of view controllers. It sounds to me more like a job for `transition⁠From⁠View:to⁠View:⁠du⁠ra⁠ti⁠on:⁠opt⁠io⁠ns:​completion:` - i.e., just replace one view with another, with animation.

Comment: I've been thinking about that, but I've decided that it is unclear to me what you ultimately _want_ to do, so I can't quite tell you _how_ to do it. What is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: I mean, for example, if you don't really want to push one view controller on top of another in a user-navigable stack, then why are you using a navigation controller interface at all?

Comment: I want to have a nice transition when switching from one to the other.

Comment: Aha. So why not use a view transition?

Comment: In other words, why use view controllers at all if all you want to do is switch views? You can switch views with animation, easily. That is what a transition animation is for.

Comment: I have them as separate view controllers. The way you suggested seems to work fine, is there anything particularly wrong with the method you suggested?

Comment: I don't really know if there's anything _wrong_ with it, but please do consider whether `transition⁠From⁠View:to⁠View:⁠du⁠ra⁠ti⁠on:⁠opt⁠io⁠ns:​completion:` would not be a better way.

Comment: Unfortunately, this deals with views whereas I have separate view controllers to avoid code clutter.

Comment: I'm wondering whether maybe you are misusing view controllers to do for you the work that could just as well be done by a decent object architecture. However, I am _not_ criticizing! Nor is there necessarily anything wrong with your way. It is an interesting problem.

Comment: Essentially, I have a menu (menu view controller) and the menu points to various mini games. I just decided to use push and pop, thus the menu is never really deallocated, but the minigames are. Not exactly what I wanted but it works.

Comment: It made sense to me to have a view controller for each game since they are all independent of each other and take up an entire screen.

Comment: However each game inherits game view controller which inherits master view controller.

Comment: But you could have "each game inherits game controller which inherits master game controller" (but is not a view controller) and have one view controller which swaps game controllers when it swaps views/games. For example in my apps that are games, neither Board nor Game is the view controller; the view controller _has_ a Board object and a Game object.